# Problem sending data to nightscout from phone apps

Tags: heroku, atlas

I am running Nightscout on Heroku with an Atlas db. My phone apps are not sending data to nightscout successfully. I was told that there is something wrong on the server side and the issue is highlighted on the screenshot. I'd be grateful to anyone who can help. I'm not technical. The offending section appears to be:

2020-08-28T22:14:20.950759+00:00 app[web.1]: Error inserting the device status object user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [heroku_5c31xmqr.devicestatus]
2020-08-28T22:14:22.360826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/v1/devicestatus" host=johnsbgdata.herokuapp.com request_id=6776092e-3228-4c20-8a52-82e9c83576c7 fwd="3.11.203.168" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=548 protocol=https

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usCF3.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please put the error message into the body of your question (and maybe the title).  That will make it easier for people to search for, and answer, your question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this. It was a database permissions error. It was READ. When I changed it to READ/WRITE and restarted the dynos, it was fixed :)